# Flow - How to retrieve first value of a collection variable?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, automated-process

I have to use an Autolaunched Flow to automate the following task:

1. Retrieve all the certain object's records which meet a certain criteria.
2. If the size of the collection is `1` - assign some field values from the only record to the one which originally triggered the flow.

**The only idea I came up with:**

1. Retrieve records to the collection variable.
2. Iterate through this collection and with every loop count increment the sizeCounter (default set to `0`) variable
3. If the size variable equals to `1` - **retrieve records again, but now put only "the first one" to the new, single record variable**

Looks like a very poor solution but I can't find any alternative. Is anyone aware of a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you want to retrieve all the object records and not only the record which triggered in first place?

Comment: Because I need to know that there's only one record meeting filter's criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring '20, you can use the [GetFirst action in the CollectionProcessors package.](https://unofficialsf.com/list-actions-for-flow/)

Comment: The above package would not install in my sandbox.  I'm waiting for SF Support to find out what the error message is.

Comment: Brian, try taking the install url above and replacing 'login' with  'test'

Comment: I'm aware of that; it was something else.  In any case, I was able to get the first element in a collection variable by using loops.  Not very user-friendly but it gets the job done.

Comment: Note that the GetFirst action will not work on string collections, only object record collections.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, since the addition of native [Collection Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_filter_collection.htm&type=5&release=236) in Flow (as of Spring '22) you can do the following:

1. Filter your collection so that only 1 result should be returned (if more than 1 result is returned, this solution will still only return a single collection entry)
2. Create a Loop element that iterates on the new Filtered Collection
3. In the For Each path assign the Current Item from the Loop to a new variable
4. Use a Connector to exit the Loop to the next Element in the Flow right after the assignment

It looks something like this:
[image]